# Change all external links using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

I want to change all external links on my blog (blogspot here, that's why I'm looking for jQuery code) without changing the posting of my blog because I need a lot of work if I do that.

For example, my website is `example.com`.
I want to change all external links to

```
http://example.com/p/go.html?url=http://externallink.com
```

without need for any changes on my blog post. I don't have any idea to start with.

**SOLVED: https://gist.github.com/2342509** Thanks everyone :D I just need to change it a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery you can try:

```
// DOM ready
$(function(){
    $('a[target="_blank"]').prop('href', 'http://example.com/p/go.html?url=http://externallink.com');
});
```

Ofcourse this will only work if you have set the `target="_blank"` property/attribute in HTML and if you want all links to open the same url. This idea derives from the fact you want to have external links open automatically in a different tab/window.

If this is not the required functionality, you can use a custom `data-` attribute in a similar way. Only difference is you will need to loop each link, and get the data from it.

```
// DOM ready
$(function(){
    $('a[data-href]').each(function(){
        var anc = $(this),
            href = anc.prop('href'),
            dataHref = anc.data('href');

        anc.prop('href', href + '?url=' + dataHref);
    });
});
```

HTML example:

```
<a href="http://example.com/p/go.html" data-href="http://externallink.com">external link</a>
```

And now you will probably need to add more information if that is still not what you want.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. The OP doesn't provide this information and the clue is within it's own domain (example.com?), running the external link through his `go.html` page. Now I wonder what will happen there ^^

Comment: `<?php header("Location:".$_REQUEST['url'])?>` should take care of that :)

Answer (score 0):

Going off of @Tim Vermaelan's answer, you could try this, which will check for every link that doesn't start with your website's URL without relying on it being `target="_blank"`:

```
$('a:not([href^="http://yoursite.com"])').prop('href', 'http://example.com/p/go.html?url=http://externallink.com');
```